# How to detect "different object types" in JavaScript? (array vs Json vs Date etc...)

Tags: javascript

For the purpose of creating a condition while recursively iterating over a JSON object, I'm trying to find a clean way to differentiate different object types.

Consider this:

```
var aJSON     = {"foo" : 1, "bar" : 2};
var anArray   = [1,2,3,4,5];
var aDate     = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z');
var anISODate = user.timesTheyLoggedIn[0] // comes from MongoDB

console.log(typeof aJSON);     // object
console.log(typeof anArray);   // object
console.log(typeof aDate);     // object
console.log(typeof anISODate); // object
```

All types of objects are 'objects' with no more info.

For now, my use case only requires detecting an ISODate object, so I'm taking advantage of ISODate objects having a resetTime function to differentiate them from others, like so:

```
if (typeof(val) === "object" && val.resetTime === undefined) { //do stuff...
```

But there must be a cleaner, better way to detect what kind of object an object is, a `val.isArray()` kinda thing...

How would do it?

PS: "different object types" is in quotes because there really is only one object type in JS, right?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) `aJSON` is an object _not a JSON formatted string_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are a class, like `Date`, you can use `instanceof` like so:

```
(new Date() instanceof Date)
```

Which evaluates to `true`.

The same can be applied to arrays as long as you don't use iframes:

```
([] instanceof Array)
```

But you have to find *your own way* for types that aren't classes.

If you don't have to stick to plain JavaScript, you could switch to Typescript, where you can also describe types.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `obj.constructor.name`:

```js
var tst = 1 > 0;
var num = 3.141592;
var obj = {a:1};
var arr = [1,2];
var dat = new Date();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

console.log(tst.constructor.name);
console.log(num.constructor.name);
console.log(obj.constructor.name);
console.log(arr.constructor.name);
console.log(dat.constructor.name);
console.log(xhr.constructor.name);
```

I'm not sure how well this will work with e.g. the Mongo type. Please try and let us know!

Comment: Just tried it with the ISODate coming from MongoDB and it gave me `Date` 
Good enough!